# Find P(Y=y | X=x) when X is a continuous random variable

Tags: probability, bayesian, random-variable, continuous-data

could someone help me understand how to find the probability $\Pr(F=f_1 | X=x)$ by using the inputs below, where $X$ is a continuous random variable?

**Note:** I know that probabilities of specific values of continuous random variables (i.e. not intervals) is 0, however I *think* I heard somewhere that there is a variation of the Bayes theorem by which densities can be used in place of probabilities, and I hope to use this to answer the question that is detailed below.

### Question Details:

Let:

- $\mathcal{X} = [a, b]$ be the universal set of samples.
- $\mathcal{F} = \{f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_n\}$ be the set of processes that generate samples in $\mathcal{X}$.
- $X$ be a random variable that takes values in $\mathcal{X}$.
- $F$ be a random variable that takes values in $\mathcal{F}$.
- For any $1 \le i \le n$, $X_i$ be a random variable that takes values in $\mathcal{X}$ as generated by process $f_i \in \mathcal{F}$.
- $\Pr(X)$ be the PDF of r.v. $X$.
- $\Pr(F)$ be the PMF of r.v. $F$.
- For any $1 \le i \le n$, $\Pr(X_i)$ be the PDF of r.v. $X_i$.

Suppose that you are given these as input:

- Some $x$ where $x \in \mathcal{X}$.
- $\Pr(X)$.
- $\Pr(F)$.
- For any $1 \le i \le n$, $\Pr(X_i)$.

Then the question is: what is $\Pr(F=f_1 | X=x)$?

---

### A first guess on a solution:

Let:

- $PDFX(x)$ be the value of the PDF $\Pr(X)$ at point $x$.
- For any $1 \le i \le n$, $PDFX_i(x)$ be the value of the PDF $\Pr(X_i)$ at point $x$.

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\Pr(F=f_1 | X=x) &= \frac{\Pr(X=x|F=f_1) \Pr(F=f_1)}{\Pr(X=x)}\\\
&= \frac{PDFX_1(x) \Pr(F=f_1)}{PDFX(x)}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Any thoughts?

Comment: With only the inputs $Pr(x)$ and $Pr(F)$ [terrible notations by the way!], you cannot find the joint distribution of $(F,X)$ hence cannot apply Bayes' theorem.

Comment: @Xi'an could you please point out where in the equation (last equation) there is a need for the joint distribution $(F,X)$ that is not in the input? Additionally, you you also please point out why the notation is terrible, and how to fix it? :) -- thank you!

Comment: This is why our elders and betters left us measure theory.

Comment: Xi'an is correct, you haven't allowed yourself $Pr(X=x | F=f_1)$.  Recall $p(a|b)p(b)=p(a,b)$.

Comment: @conjectures, but I have given myself $f_{x|F=f_1}(x)$, which in my terrible notation is $PDFX_1$ as I personally think that $PDFX_1 = f_{x|F=f_1}(x)$, do you agree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result looks correct to me. One way to justify this mixture of continuous and discrete random variables is by means of generalized functions, namely, [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

Discrete random variables don't have a density because their cumulative distribution function is not differentiable at the points of interest. Generalized functions can help with that – just as any polynomial has a root on a complex plane, every function has a (weak) derivative.

So for discrete r.v. $F$ taking values $f_1, \dots, f_n$ with probabilities $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n$ corresponding pdf would be

$$
p_F(f) = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \delta(f - f_i)
$$

Now we can apply Bayes' theorem:

$$
p(F = f | X = x)
 = \frac{p_{X|F}(x|F = f) p_F(f)}{p_X(x)}
 = \frac{p_{X|F}(x|F = f) \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \delta(f - f_i)}{p_X(x)}\\
 = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\alpha_i p_{X|F}(x|F = f)}{p_X(x)} \delta(f - f_i)
$$

Note all quantities involved were densities. It's easy to see that resulting density corresponds to a discrete r.v. with PMF (note that each summand is non-zero only if $f - f_i = 0$).

$$
\text{Pr}(F = f_i | X = x) = \frac{\alpha_i p_{X|F}(x|F = f_i)}{p_X(x)}
$$

Comment: I don't get how is this related, can you explain please? What I see is that you are trying to explain how to get a PDF out of a discrete random variable. But the question is about how to get probabilities that are conditioned on continuous random variables.

Comment: PDF of a discrete r.v. is the first part of my answer. I then proceed to calculating conditional pdf, and transforming it into a PMF.

Comment: PDF of discrete r.v.? I thought these have only PMFs instead, no?

Comment: Excuse me, but did you read my answer? I explicitly said that for discrete r.v. we need to use generalized functions to define a density function.